# Unable to correctly use Pandas Interpolate over a series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, interpolation, series

I am trying to use the interpolation functionality provided by Pandas,   [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) but for some reason, cannot get my Series to adjust to the correct values. I casted them to a float64, but that did not appear to help. Any recommendations?

**The code:**

```
for feature in price_data:
    print price_data[feature]
    print "type:"
    print type(price_data[feature])
    newSeries = price_data[feature].astype(float).interpolate()
    print "newSeries: "
    print newSeries
```

**The output:**

```
0    178.9000
1      0.0000
2    178.1200
Name: open_price, dtype: object
type:
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
newSeries: 
0    178.90
1      0.00
2    178.12
Name: open_price, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is nothing to interpolate.  I'm assuming you want to interpolate the value where zero is.  In that case, replace the zero with `np.nan` then interpolate.  One way to do this is

```
price_data.where(price_data != 0, np.nan).interpolate()

0    178.90
1    178.51
2    178.12
Name: open_price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Completely overlooked that... Thanks for your time!